# What to do if someone swears at religion?

Tags: practical-islam

Someone was swearing at God and our religion and using words like “gay” etc to try and insult the religion. How do you respond? Do you swear back or attack them or what?

Also they try to burn Quran do we have to attack them to protect the Quran?

Answer (score 1):

“And the servants of the Most Merciful are those who walk upon the earth easily, and when the ignorant address them [harshly], they say [words of] peace.”
-Qur’an 25:63